# Jquery height auto detect and change if less than

Tags: jquery, height, document

i've coded the following jquery to change the height of `#dash-nav` if it is less than that of `#dash-content-wrap`. It's for a basic vertical navigationon a dashboard.

```
if ($('#dash-nav').height() < $('#dash-content-wrap').height()) {
    $("#dash-nav").height( $("#dash-content-wrap").height() );
}
```

The code works absolutely as expected in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycvNd/4/), **however** does *not* on my live site.

I've tried loading the script using both of the following methods and neither present any differences:

- `(window).load`
- `(document).ready`

*Any ideas & help, greatly appreciated! Thank you*

Comment: what's the url of the live site? could just be a caching issue, have you tried clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: yea i've cleared my browser cache a few times, thought this would be the issue right away. I'm unable to give the url as its a dev server

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle link is asking for username and password (Basic authentication). `$(document).ready(function(){...})` should work absolutely fine as it is fired only after the DOM elements are completely loaded

Please make your css classes are correct. My guess is if you might be having float:left somewhere inside `dash-nav`, the height may not giving a correct value. You can try `clear:both` and see if that fixes the issue. This is just my guess.

Also try to do this:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    components();
},1000);
```

inside `$(document).ready()` giving a delay of 1000 milliseconds.

The above code is just for debugging purpose. You shouldn't use it and instead try to fix the *real* issue but it should atleast let you know whether the problem is not loading of `dash-nav` or something else.

**Edit:** To clarify what I am talking about, please see this jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/kfdbz/3/

Unless you uncomment: `<div style="clear:both"></div>` you will get a height of `0`

Comment: adding timeout works again in my fiddle but not on live browser, checking css clear/floats now

Comment: @Matt: This is strange. You should probably check CSS issues only on your LIVE server if you happen to change the LIVE css recently. See my edit regarding the issue I was talking about. Did you try that?

Comment: yea everything that is floated inside dash-nav is also using clear:both;